# php table colour rows group by date

Tags: php, css, colors, jscript, group

New to stackoverflow.
About 5 years ago I built a booking site and haven't touch php since, so very very rusty. All is working well with it. However I want to make some updates. As part of the update I have a table that is grouped by date from a Mysql table. This table can now have 1, 2, 3 or 4 results for the same date. To make things clearer for the user I would like to colour the rows by date. It can be grey for one date, white for the next, grey for the next as so on. I do have code to colour all the dates, unfortunately I can end up with consecutive dates with the same colour.

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($results)) {
    $id_array[] = $row["id"];
    $Fltnum_array[] = $row["fltnum"];
    $Date_array[] = $row["Date"];
    $Name_array[] = $row["Name"];
    $Lesson_array[] = $row["vouchertype"];
    $Vnum_array[] = $row["vnum"];
    $Phone_array[] = $row["phone"];
    $Email_array[] = $row["email"];
    $Ten_array[] = $row["Ten"];
    $Ten1_array[] = $row["Ten1"];
    $Eleven_array[] = $row["Eleven"];
    $Twelve_array[] = $row["Twelve"];
    $Thirteen_array[] = $row["thirteen"];
    $Fourteen_array[] = $row["Fourteen"];
    $Fithteen_array[] = $row["Fifteen"];
    $Sixteen_array[] = $row["Sixteen"]; 



}



<body style="left: 50%; position: absolute; height:1000px; ">
<div id="apDiv3">
<?php
    echo "<form action='#' name='mainForm' method='post'>
       <table border='1' align='center' cellpadding='3' cellspacing='0' >
           <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Flight Type</th>
                <th>Date</th>
                <th>10:00</th>
                <th>10:00</th>
                <th>11:00</th>
                <th>12:00</th>
                <th>13:00</th>
                <th>14:00</th>
                <th>15:00</th>
                <th>16:00</th> 
             </tr>";
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($id_array); $i++) {
        $id = $id_array[$i];
        $Fltnum = $Fltnum_array[$i];
        $Date = $Date_array[$i];
        $Name = $Name_array[$i];
        $Lesson = $Lesson_array[$i];
        $Vnum = $Vnum_array[$i];
        $Phone = $Phone_array[$i];
        $Email = $Email_array[$i];
        $Ten = $Ten_array[$i];
        $Ten1 = $Ten1_array[$i];
        $Eleven = $Eleven_array[$i];
        $Twelve = $Twelve_array[$i];
        $Thirteen = $Thirteen_array[$i];
        $Fourteen = $Fourteen_array[$i];
        $Fithteen = $Fithteen_array[$i];
        $Sixteen = $Sixteen_array[$i];
        $set_checked = ($Ten < 1) ? 'checked="checked"' : '';
        $set_checked0 = ($Ten1 < 1) ? 'checked="checked"' : '';
        $set_checked1 = ($Eleven < 1) ? 'checked="checked"' : '';
        $set_checked2 = ($Twelve < 1) ? 'checked="checked"' : '';
        $set_checked3 = ($Thirteen < 1) ? 'checked="checked"' : '';
        $set_checked4 = ($Fourteen < 1) ? 'checked="checked"' : '';
        $set_checked5 = ($Fithteen < 1) ? 'checked="checked"' : '';
        $set_checked6 = ($Sixteen < 1) ? 'checked="checked"' : '';
        $newDate = date("d-m-Y", strtotime($Date));         
    echo "
        <input type='hidden' name='id[]' value='$id'>
        <input type='hidden' name='Fltnum-$id' value='$Fltnum'> 
        <td><input input type='text' name='Name-$id' value='$Name'></td>
        <td><input input type='text' name='Lesson-$id' value='$Lesson'></td>
        <td><input type='text' name='Date-$id' value='$newDate'> </td>
        <input type='hidden' name='vnum-$id' value='$Vnum'>
        <input type='hidden' name='Phone-$id' value='$Phone'>
        <input type='hidden' name='Email-$id' value='$Email'>";
        ...
        echo                
        "</tr>";    
        }
        echo "<tr align='center'><td colspan='8'><input type='submit' name='submit' value='Make Booking' ></td></tr></table>";  
    echo "</form>";
 ?>
</div>
```

I have spent a couple of days on this also looking through the forums.

To Add a little more detail, This is the result as is:

[image]

and this is what I would like:

[image]

Comment: If the date of the current record you are outputting is different from the one of the previous record - then toggle your class between `odd` and `even` at this point.

Comment: FYI, you are creating invalid HTML there. You can not put `input` directly into a `tr`, they need to be inside the table cells. (And an actual opening `<tr>` tag also appears to be missing.)

Comment: I have tried to toggel between odd and even on the id, The trouble is that the table can have id1 and id2 for the same date.

Comment: you can use css to color rows `tr:nth-child(odd)` for example

Comment: Thanks Dale, I have tried that, I am properly doing this wrong when I do this, I get 1 row grey the next row white and so on. I need the rows alternating by date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears as though you want to alternate colors for the rows, but only if the date is different than the previous row (so consecutive dates that are the same will appear the same color).

You could do something like this by comparing the date in your loop with the previous date and then applying a color from an array based on whether or not they are the same.

```
$backgrounds = ["#FFFFFF", "#EEEEEE"];
$currentBackground = 0;

for ($i = 0; $i < count($id_array); $i++) {
  $id = $id_array[$i];
  $Fltnum = $Fltnum_array[$i];
  $Date = $Date_array[$i];
  $Name = $Name_array[$i];
  $Lesson = $Lesson_array[$i];
  $Vnum = $Vnum_array[$i];
  $Phone = $Phone_array[$i];
  $Email = $Email_array[$i];
  $Ten = $Ten_array[$i];
  $Ten1 = $Ten1_array[$i];
  $Eleven = $Eleven_array[$i];
  $Twelve = $Twelve_array[$i];
  $Thirteen = $Thirteen_array[$i];
  $Fourteen = $Fourteen_array[$i];
  $Fithteen = $Fithteen_array[$i];
  $Sixteen = $Sixteen_array[$i];
  $set_checked = ($Ten < 1) ? 'checked="checked"' : '';
  $set_checked0 = ($Ten1 < 1) ? 'checked="checked"' : '';
  $set_checked1 = ($Eleven < 1) ? 'checked="checked"' : '';
  $set_checked2 = ($Twelve < 1) ? 'checked="checked"' : '';
  $set_checked3 = ($Thirteen < 1) ? 'checked="checked"' : '';
  $set_checked4 = ($Fourteen < 1) ? 'checked="checked"' : '';
  $set_checked5 = ($Fithteen < 1) ? 'checked="checked"' : '';
  $set_checked6 = ($Sixteen < 1) ? 'checked="checked"' : '';
  $newDate = date("d-m-Y", strtotime($Date));

  // Only check previous value if we are not on the first row
  if($i > 0) {
    // If the date is the same, do not change backgrounds
    // Otherwise, toggle between backgrounds
    $currentBackground = ($Date_array[$i] == $Date_array[$i-1]) ? $currentBackground : ($currentBackground == 0) ? 1 : 0;
  }
  // This just sets the color from our backgrounds array
  $background = $backgrounds[$currentBackground];
  
  echo "
    <tr style='background: $background;'>
      <td><input type='hidden' name='id[]' value='$id'></td>
      <td><input type='hidden' name='Fltnum-$id' value='$Fltnum'></td>
      <td><input input type='text' name='Name-$id' value='$Name'></td>
      <td><input input type='text' name='Lesson-$id' value='$Lesson'></td>
      <td><input type='text' name='Date-$id' value='$newDate'> </td>
      <td><input type='hidden' name='vnum-$id' value='$Vnum'></td>
      <td><input type='hidden' name='Phone-$id' value='$Phone'></td>
      <td><input type='hidden' name='Email-$id' value='$Email'></td>
    </tr>";    
}
```

Comment: Thanks Sup3rkirby, Your a star, that has sorted. I would add a point, but the system will not let me as I am too new. Thank you so much again.